# What are the allowable image file extension, doc and excel file extensions and also video file extension for moxiemanager on tinymce 5?

Tags: tinymce, moxiemanager, tinymce-5

I used moxiemanager on my updated tinymce 5 community edition. I put in common video extensions like .mov .m4v .avi .flv and .swf but it won't allow to upload those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

As MoxieManager is a commercial product feel free to open a support ticket on our support site at support.tiny.cloud and we can help address this issue.